# Search for address of person contacts through current employeer

Tags: search, relationships

I'm looking for a way to search for contacts for which we have an address of their current employeer on record. How do I do that?

I often find myself in this situation, wanting to find contacts based on the fields of an other contact, one relation "distant". Is there a simple way to do these searches or is that always a programmed "Custom Search"?

As a bonus question, we tend to not add address information on the person, but keep that on the organizations. But it seems CiviCRM is built for "single contact" handling, rather than relation-based searches. Is there a way to handle this in a practical way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the top of extended search you can chose the type of result to search for. There's an entry like "Relationship to contact". Take this one and select 'Employee' relationship below. Your search input now applies to your organizations but the displayed results will be their employees.